# rpush APNS notifications not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apple-push-notifications

I can't seem to figure out why my apple push notifications aren't working. My sandbox and production certificates are good until mid 2016. They were working at one point. When my app went live though, I noticed that they were not working.

On the server side, where I trigger the push notifications upon a user answering another users question, I am doing everything correctly still. Retrieving the device token from my DB, etc.

```
    def send_notification(question_user, answer_user, alert, sound, data)
        if question_user && answer_user
            rememeber_tokens_for_user = RememberToken.where("user_id = ?", question_user.id)
            if rememeber_tokens_for_user.size > 0
                rememeber_tokens_for_user.each do |remember_token|
                    n = Rpush::Apns::Notification.new
                    n.app = Rpush::Apns::App.find_by_name("Roto Forum")
                    n.device_token = remember_token.device_token
                    n.alert = alert
                    n.badge = unread_answers_count_for_user_id(question_user.id)
                    n.sound = sound
                    n.data = data
                    n.save
                end

                Rpush.embed
            end
        end
    end
```

However, no users end up with push notifications. I'm not sure where to start debugging this. It's on heroku. Does rpush supply some sort of logs, and if so, how would I obtain these from heroku? Does rpush have a table full of notifications in pending or sent/failed state? What's the best way to debug this?

Comment: hi @chris P were you able to solve this? i hv the same issue ryt now

Comment: @KingsleySimon yeah I was. It turns out it was some issue with rpush. I went nuts deleting all provisioning profiles and certificates and completely cleaned house. It didn't work. Finally I decided to get rid of rpush, and tried jpoz/APNS gem. Worked like a charm.